# git зависает на rebase interactive. Как это можно починить?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Делаю

```
User@User-PC MINGW64 /d/!!!DESKTOP/Git полигон и схемы/devBob (master)
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

И гит зависает. Если  не прервать операцию - на час и больше без каких-либо сообщений.

Проблема появилась когда сделал rebase -i с прерыванием по rebase --abort.

Как это можно починить?

UPD. Развернули пока репозиторий из облака заново.
Мне кажется проблема была из-за где-то висящего у разработчика окна с редактором. 
Как будет время попробую воспроизвести ошибку и отписаться о результатах.

Comment: может быть, у вас там где-то висит открытое окно редактора с файлом, в котором были конфликты при ребейзе?

Comment: что показывает `git status`?

Comment: Часто выхожу из rebase через --abort, но никогда не сталкивался с подобной ошибкой. Сделайте копию всей папки проекта, а потом покажите `git status`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, отдельно спасибо, разобрались с вашей подсказкой

Answer (score 3):

Итог:
В конфиге гит для rebase -i был указан другой редактор по умолчанию (Sublime вместо VIM). 
Иногда этот же редактор используется для быстрых правок в коде.

Поэтому при решении конфликтов, если этот редактор открыт (не обязательно на файлах с конфликтами) - rebase -i иногда зависает и не двигается дальше. 
Если его закрыть - процесс продолжается корректно.

Comment: Если в качестве редактора прописывать не просто Sublime Text, а с флагом `-w`, этой проблемы не возникает, и команды git продолжаются при закрытии соответствующих вкладок, как и полагается. Можно также добавить флаг `-n`, чтобы для операции открывалось новое окно редактора.

Comment: @D-side увы в нашем случае это почему-то не помогает. В конфиге уже стоит:
 editor = \"/d/IDE/Sublime Text Build 3065/sublime_text.exe\" -n -w. Это корректная запись?

Comment: Сложно сказать, я такую схему использую в Linux и исполняемый файл у меня называется `subl`, и редактор у меня указан не в конфигурации Git, а в переменной среды `EDITOR`. Вроде всё.